# Create a Ms Word template based on another template using c#

Tags: c#, ms-word, word-automation

I tried to create a word template based on another Exist template, I have already tried with .docx using bookmarks and it is work but i have no idea how can i change the extension from .docx to .dotx

Here is the code I've tried

```
        object outputf = document.FullName.Replace(".docx", ".dotx");
        object fileFormat = Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatTemplate;
        document.SaveAs(ref outputf, ref fileFormat, ref oMissing,
    ref oMissing,  ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
    ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
    ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
```

But it does not result in a .dotx that Word can work with. Any ideas?

Comment: Here at SO, we don't spit ball ideas with you, rather help you with very small concepts, like finding a bug, or algorithim, etc.

Comment: i tried somthing like that but that doesnt word am begining and i need help   ==>                                                                                                         object outputf = document.FullName.Replace(".docx", ".dotx");
      object fileFormat = Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatTemplate;
     document.SaveAs(ref outputf,
     ref fileFormat, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
     ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
    ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
    ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);

Comment: Please add the code you've tried as well as a description about HOW it "doesn't work" to your question. click the EDIT link under the question to do so. Be sure to correctly format your code so that it's readable! Without this, your question is likely to be closed as "unclear" and that would be too bad because it's actually a useful question about Word...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to turn a Word document (docx) into a template (dotx) is to use the SaveAs command, specifying not only the file name parameter but also the FILE TYPE. This takes a Enum, as you show in your comment.

The trick is that the Enum MUST fit the file extension. I believe wdFormatTemplate is the old .dot file format. Look for an Enum like WdFormatXMLTemplate. (I'd look it up for you, but MSDN isn't letting me log in to the Language Reference...)

Note: It's always important that you describe HOW something "doesn't work". For example, any error messages.

Comment: Tnx a lot i find the solution with some changes in proprites of saveFileDialog and using the SaveAs Command, but First my Question was about how can i create a Ms word Template from a existing template  i found a problem with how can i change the Default Exetension of the Document Created to became .dotx

Comment: You are correct. I got the error `Incompatible file type and file extension` when trying to save dotx with `wdFormatTemplate` (enum: 1). Worked when switching to `WdFormatXMLTemplate` (enum: 14)!